# View Composer not working in my Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to share variables on multiple views so i tried the view composer but it is not working as its not passing variables and is there any way to debug it

**ComposerServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            'layouts.admin.dashboard',
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\StatComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

So now here will be the Composer File

**StatComposer.php**

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Analytics;
use Spatie\Analytics\Period;
use App\Libraries\GoogleAnalytics;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class StatComposer
{
    /**
     * Create a movie composer.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $result = GoogleAnalytics::topCountries();
        $country = $result->pluck('country');
        $country_sessions = $result->pluck('sessions');

        $topBrowsers = GoogleAnalytics::topBrowsers();
        $browser = $topBrowsers->pluck('browser');
        $browser_sessions = $topBrowsers->pluck('sessions');

        $totalPageViews = GoogleAnalytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews();
        $date = $totalPageViews->pluck('date');
        $visitors = $totalPageViews->pluck('visitors');
        $pageViews = $totalPageViews->pluck('pageViews');
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('country', 'country_sessions', 'browser', 'browser_sessions','date','visitors','pageViews');
    }
}
```

So I am unable to find way to debug it as the variables are not passing to the view i am trying to pass them to and the view is giving error of undefined variable.

Comment: you can do same thing with help of middleware more about https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Comment: @GauravGupta sir i want to pass multiple variables to multiple variables do you have any solution

Comment: check the use of middleware it will definitely help you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your declaring a lot of variables without providing the values in the compose function.  Also your not actually saving the data anywhere. It should be like this.

```
protected $country;

/**
 * Create a movie composer.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $result = GoogleAnalytics::topCountries();
    $this->country = $result->pluck('country');
}

/**
 * Bind data to the view.
 *
 * @param  View  $view
 * @return void
 */
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('country', $this->country);
}
```

Note we are declaring the classes property at the top, then saving to that property and  then setting the 'country' variable in the with method with the $this->country property.

Comment: sorry sir it's now working it's still showing undefined variable in the new view i called the variable.

Comment: is that in the layouts.admin.dashboard view? Have you done a dd() to make sure the composer is being called and that the $result is passing data?

Comment: Also are you passing to the with individual variables or values?

Comment: yes i am passing individual variable and i tried dd() but it its not working so may be composer is not being called on dashboard view